# Proving that $ax^2 + bx + c = dx^2 + ex + f$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, formal-proofs

So given  $ax^2 + bx + c =  dx^2  + ex + f$ and that it holds true for all values of x:

Prove $a = d$, $b = e$, and $c = f$.

What I have done so far is set the equation equal to zero and factor the desired variables together and out:

$ax^2 + bx + c - dx^2  - ex - f = 0$

$ax^2 - dx^2 + bx - ex + c - f = 0$

$(a-d)x^2 + (b-e)x + (c-f) = 0$

Now once I prove that $a - d$, $b - e$, and $c - f$ are all equal to zero, then everything would be all over.

But unfortunately I do not know how to proceed here. I know it probably has to do with polynomial degree root limits or something, but I am fuzzy on the precise procedure and would appreciate the help on finishing this off.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the roots of a second order equation? If yes, do you know how many solutions you have to expect?

Comment: if this equation holds for all real $x$, so we can set $x=0$ and we get $$c=f$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.Since the equation:
$$
(a-d)x^2 + (b-e)x+(c-f)=0
$$
is true for all values of $x$, we can substitute values of $x$ and the resulting equation will still be true:

Put $x=0$, then we get $c-f=0$, so $c=f$.

Now our equation simplifies to :
$$
(a-d)x^2 + (b-e)x=0 \implies x((a-d)x+(b-e)) = 0
$$

Take $x=1$ here: $(a-d) + (b-e) = 0$

Take $x=-1$ here:$(d-a) + (b-e) = 0$

Add the two equations: $2(b-e) = 0$, so $b-e=0$ and $b=e$

Finally, we are left with $(a-d)x^2=0$ for all values of $x$. Put $x=1$ to get $a-d=0$ so $a=d$. This method required no kind of complicated method and can be generalized to other polynomials.

Comment: Thank you! However, I actually found a potential alternate method: using $(a-d)x^2 + x(b-e) = 0$  and dividing on both sides by x, then setting the $(a-d)x$  to zero, thus making $b - c = 0$. would this work as well?

Comment: Also, I believe that you wrote b = c?? Did you mean b = e?

Comment: Abosultely. This would work too. And thank you for pointing out the error.

Comment: @KMoy I should add that division by $x$ should not be done because if $x=0$ then you can't divide. That's why I had to take two different values t that point, not just substitute $x=0$ and get a result.